# ios - How to extend location tracking time using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am playing with the IOS location tracking using swift 4. I see that the method `didUpdateLocations` executes every single second

[image: Log of position tracking]

If there is a way to increase the time from 1 second to n seconds, please let me know. I think it can reduce battery consuming issue of the app later.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where does that '1 second' come from?

Comment: There is no option to change that time. You can apply  Accuracy to location manager see this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationaccuracy

Comment: It's not base on time, it's base on the distance https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter

Comment: @QuocNguyen: Yes, the answer below change the distance and everything works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

This line of code solved my problem. It will notify the LocationManager every 100 meters

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0;
```

Thank you: [How to stop multiple times method calling of didUpdateLocations() in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292835/how-to-stop-multiple-times-method-calling-of-didupdatelocations-in-ios)