# How do I take the values of Lat and Long out of the function so they can be used anywhere else in the VC?

Tags: swift

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
                                          longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 13.0)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let Lat = "\(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude)"
    let Long = "\(userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)"

}
```

How do I extract the values of Lat and Long out of the function? I've attempted a return and also tried sending the values to the app delegate to be later called back but nothing worked. The values get passed to the app delegate but are not able to be called back into the same VC they came from. I'm new to swift so I sure there has to be a simpler method of getting them out that I'm overlooking.

Comment: What about saving them in variables in the vc scope?

Comment: have you get lat and long in didUpdateLocations delegate method?

Comment: @Joakim I think I attempted that and kept getting blank values.

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya ya I got the string values but just need to take them out the function

Comment: @Abe Use singletons or save to user defaults..But singleton will be fine.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077008/locationmanagerdidupdatelocations-always-be-called-several-times/32088366#32088366)

Answer (score 0):

Just define `userLocation` variable outside the `didUpdateLocation` function and then update the value inside the `didUpdateLocation` function like below:

```
var userLocation: CLLocation?

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    userLocation = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
                                          longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 13.0)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func getUpdatedLocation() {
    let Lat = "\(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude)"
    let Long = "\(userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)"
}
```

You can find out lat & long from anywhere like my `getUpdatedLocation()` function.

Comment: func getUpdatedLocation() {
    let Lat = "\(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude)"
    let Long = "\(userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)"
}

Comment: when using this method the values come out to be nil

Comment: Location may be nil for first updates, but when gps kicks in you will have updates that will give you your location

Comment: locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()     why this line in your code ? @Abe

Comment: go to this link and make the changes for swift 3 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25074531/

Comment: welcome bro . you may up vote this , if you think helpful .